# One-liner searched in Ruby on Rails for altering attribute in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, for an ActiveRecord `class MySettings`, is there a more elegant option to say

```
s = MySettings.last
s.do_updates = true
s.save
```

in one line?

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but is chaining allowed in ruby on rails? like... are they using a factory pattern?

Comment: @Kristian - the `s.do_updates = true` call would break the chain as it does not return the object but rather the new value. This would work: `MySettings.last.save` but of course, it does nothing.

Comment: sure, but you could set that as a global, and then perform the chain

Comment: @Kristian what do you mean? "set that as a global" - you mean creating some defaults?

Comment: @YoLudke yes actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes):

```
  MySettings.last.update_attributes :do_updates => true
```

Comment: Sine it's a single attribute, consider: `update_attribute :do_updates, true`. I just wanted to mention this. +1

Comment: I haven't tried that in Rails 3. But it won't work in Rails 2 for sure. `update_attribute({:do_updates, true})` this will work in rais 2. But hash with `,` seperated key,value is deprecated in rails 3

Comment: nice, I think one  should really use `update_attribute` (I was mistaken and thought update_attibute(s) was a private function)  - "Note: Though this request can be made with a partial set of the resource’s attributes, the full body of the request will still be sent in the save request to the remote service." from the documentation

Comment: @Kyle sorry, hash with `,` seperated key,value present in 1.8 and deprecated in ruby 1.9. And `update_attributes` takes hash as an argument. So I think it won't work..

Comment: @codeit - `update_attribute` does not accept a hash, it takes two arguments: the attribute and the value. It is also present in rails v1. http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute

Comment: @Kyle ohh I thought you were saying about `update_attributes`. Yes, `update_attribute` takes `name` and `value` but it is deprecated method and also it doesn't perform validations.

Comment: Please note that `update_attribute` does not cause validations to be called, per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute so it is not exactly the same thing as doing an explicit save on the record.

Answer (score 2):

[update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes)

```
MySettings.last.update_attributes(:do_updates => true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I typically would recommend `update_attributes` as the others have suggested, this is the perfect situation to use [`update_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) which is replacing [`update_attribute`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6739).
`update_attribute` is being removed in rails 4.x and will issue deprecation warnings in later 3.2.x releases.

```
MySettings.last.update_column(:do_updates, true)
```

Unlike `update_attributes`, `update_column` does not execute validations or callbacks.  If you need the ActiveRecord callbacks, definitely use `update_attrbutes`.

Comment: Nice additional information - so in general, because one always wants valid data in the db - one should really use `update_attributes` even if it's just one attribute one is changing. When you say that something is "deprecated" I think it would be nice to add the version, from your link, to mention it again: update_attribute will be deprecated in Rails 4.0

Comment: Good points @YoLudke.  I think it's actually being deprecated in 3.2.something, but I don't know which version.  I'll take a look and update my post.  It makes sense that they are deprecating it, because this is one of the most confusing things in rails.  Re: when to use update_attributes, you hit the nail on the head.  If you care about validations and callbacks, which is almost always, you want to use it.